# Problem in installing react native via expo

Tags: reactjs, npm, expo, command-line-interface, native

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/create-expo-app/-/create-expo-app-2.1.1.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'create-expo-app@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/create-expo-app/-/create-expo-app-2.1.1.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

i verified the version of npm and node i think that was not the problem i verifed the proxy ; i'm not using any proxy so i don't know where the problem comes

Comment: The link also returns 404 on my side. What command did you run

Comment: npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject

Comment: one of my friends used the same command to install react native via expo and it worked so i don't know what problem i have